# How to get latest comments from YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, data-processing

YouTube Data API allows you to get latest comment THREADs and replies to that thread via comments/list endpoint but you cannot seem to get a flattened list of comments (thread & replies merged) or latest comment replies. Maybe I'm missing something.

My requirement is I want to check the latest comments, but in order to do this, I need to scan every comment thread and compare against a local store to see what is "new" and not been seen before.

This means calling comment/threads, then looks at all replies, then repeat. You cannot run this process in parallel and each page of results requires the previous token.

Thus for a big channel with 100s of 1000s of comments it taking forever to do a basic diff of what is a new comment. This seems a little crazy to me.

Again, maybe I'm missing something. Can anyone share with the YouTube Data API how to get the latest replies/threads quickly?

Comment: My advice would be: use the comment/threads endpoints and return such data ordered by time - then (*using your local store to get the latest date*) you use that latest date as the end of retrieving the data. Example: you query the comments from a video and you already have a local store with comments until "06/21/2022", then, make again the calls to those endpoints (*ordered by time*) and *once you get a comment created on "06/21/2022", you stop making requests.

Comment: Hey @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes - the problem is the ordering by date is desc but by thread only. So for example, you could have a thread from 2 weeks ago, say for example, thread #500, that has a new reply. But the only way to know is to go through 500 threads and their replies to even know.

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately, I don't think there is an alternative using official YouTube API. You might search for *unofficial* ones available on Github, or, check if in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) are tickets with a request that matches your requierements.